# VPN for iOS Developers

Tags: iphone, ipad, networking, network-programming, vpn

I Can't find any user guide for iOS developers how i can make an VPN connection programmatically in obj-c, c or cpp.
I need to write an app which connects thru VPN and takes files from server and edit them and send back by VPN.
which librarys or some thing.
Please Any HELP! Advice??

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the VPN API is not exposed by Apple. Therefore, you cannot do it programatically.